# How to create a side by side HTML table grid?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a table with stuff in it like this:

[image]

What I have right now:

```html
<table class="table">
  <td>
    <tr>
      <div style="width: 100px;height:100px; background-color: blue;"></div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <div style="width: 100px;height:100px; background-color: red;"></div>
    </tr>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div style="width: 100px;height:200px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
  </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you use a css file or a style tag instead of inline css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rowspan`, and `td` cannot be direct child of a `table`.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.blue {
  background-color: royalblue;
  height: 100px;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="blue">1</td>
    <td class="yellow" rowspan="2">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="red">2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code must like this: use rowspan for second td

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td  style="width: 100px;height:100px; background-color: blue;"></td> 
        <td rowspan="2"  style="width: 100px;height:200px; background-color: yellow;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  style="width: 100px;height:100px; background-color: red;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly, your table syntax is off. It should look like this.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Next, what you want is the first row to have two columns, with the second column taking up the space of two rows. The next row will have one column. This can be done using rowspan.
Here's your refactored code.

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1">
      <div style="width: 100px;height:100px; background-color: blue;"></div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <div style="width: 100px;height:200px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1">
      <div style="width: 100px;height:100px; background-color: red;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```